# Desmos: How to define a constant implicitly?

Tags: graphing-functions, calculator, implicit-function

I have a project I'm doing in desmos and want to know if this is possible.

I want to be able to set some parameter, a, equal to the solution of f(x) = 0. I plugged my specific equation into Maple and it could not arrive at an explicit solution for x.

However, when I type in the equation f(x) = 0 into desmos, it does a fine job of plotting the x values for which this equation is true.

My question is this: Is it possible to take this x value(s) and set my parameter (AKA constant or 'slider') equal to it? Does desmos provide this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Desmos doesn't have a good way to do this currently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how long regression has been an available feature on Desmos.

This seems to work

```
k=3
f(x)=kx-x^2
f(A)~1
q=A
(q,f(q))
```

[image: robphy-desmos]

To get the other solution,
one could use a range in the function definition.

```
f(x)=kx-x^2 {x>1}
```

But it doesn't seem to be reliable in all cases.
For example, try to vary k with

```
f(x)=x sin(k x)
```